# Why HKCR\pngfile context menu works in Windows XP but not in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, registry, windows-7-x64, file-association

I've been trying to add a command to process PNG files on my Windows 7 64-bit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.png\OpenWithProgids]
"pngfile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pngfile\shell\PNGProcess]
@="Process"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pngfile\shell\PNGProcess\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PNGProcess\\pngproc.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice]
"Progid"="PBrush"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.png]
@="png_auto_file"
```

It works on Windows XP, but not on Windows 7 64-bit.

The same exact registry addition works for `HKCR\jpegfile` on that Windows 7 64-bit system, but the `HKCR\pngfile` doesn't work.

I double checked to verify that those entries actually exist in the right place in the registry. They do!

Baffled by this, I checked other programs that add context menu items to graphic file extension and sure enough this problem exists even with the venerable GIMP!

I tried to find information about known peculiarities regarding PNG and Windows 7 but couldn't find any.

Any idea what's so special about `pngfile` in windows 7?

Update: Following the advice below, I captured the relevant operations when I right-click a .png file (to access the context menu), which automatically re-creates the value `png_auto_file`:

```
4:05:53.3456954 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value
4:05:53.3457486 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice\Progid SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 14, Data: PBrush
4:05:53.3457983 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS 
4:05:53.3532997 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value
4:05:53.3533494 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice\Progid SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 14, Data: PBrush
4:05:53.3534160 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS 
4:05:53.3605580 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value
4:05:53.3606023 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice\Progid SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 14, Data: PBrush
4:05:53.3606462 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS 
4:05:53.3670219 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value
4:05:53.3670721 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice\Progid SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 14, Data: PBrush
4:05:53.3671219 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS 
4:05:53.3886634 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value
4:05:53.3887094 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice\Progid SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 14, Data: PBrush
4:05:53.3887554 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS 
4:05:53.4146451 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value
4:05:53.4146940 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice\Progid SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 14, Data: PBrush
4:05:53.4147417 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS 
4:05:53.7282785 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value
4:05:53.7283091 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice\Progid SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 14, Data: PBrush
4:05:53.7283375 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS 
4:05:53.7680034 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value
4:05:53.7680323 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice\Progid SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 14, Data: PBrush
4:05:53.7680595 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS 
4:05:53.7848014 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value
4:05:53.7848311 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice\Progid SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 14, Data: PBrush
4:05:53.7848591 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS 
4:05:53.8001734 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegOpenKey  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS Desired Access: Query Value
4:05:53.8002023 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegQueryValue   HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice\Progid SUCCESS Type: REG_SZ, Length: 14, Data: PBrush
4:05:53.8002303 PM  Explorer.EXE    2696    RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice    SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several reasons these keys could fail, and you've hardly provided any information so these are general troubleshooting tips

1. You didn't say, but have you linked up `.png` files to the `pngfile` ProgID? You can check the default value of `HKCR\.png`
2. Has a Default Program/`UserChoice` been assigned for `.png` files that would change the ProgID to something other than `pngfile`? You can check by looking for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice` and inspecting that ProgID
3. Is there a `HKCU` version of this "PNGProcess" verb that points to a different application or is otherwise misconfigured? Check for that key in `HKCU\Software\Classes\.png`

*Update after question edits:*

There are inconsistancies in your `.reg` file. You're adding your `PNGProcess` verb to the `pngfile` ProgID, but you're setting the `UserChoice` to `PBrush` and then you're setting the default `.png` ProgID to `png_auto_file`. That's three different ProgID's. They need to all be the same.

Comment: +1 already for an immensely helpful answer. Thank you! I updated my post based on your questions. Looks like `.png\UserChoice` is the culprit because it doesn't exist for `.jpg` which behaves as expected. I'll delete it and see what happens.

Comment: Nope. :(  I deleted `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice` but that didn't help. Mystery still remains, since all other points you mentioned seem to be benign.

Comment: But... I checked `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.‌​png\OpenWithProgids` and unlike jpgfile, it has an extra entry named **png_auto_file** that keeps being auto-generated even when I delete it! Why?

Comment: @BillTheApe Time to go another level deeper. Grab `Process Monitor` and run a capture when you observe the key being regenerated. Check if it's `explorer.exe`. Look for other keys it's checks/fails on before creating that key. Also helpful is to run a cap while opening a png file so you can get an idea of the reg key check order, so you know where to hook in with your keys.

Comment: OK, I just did as you suggested (using a filter that could help tell the forest from the trees) and I posted the result above. As you suspected, it is `Explorer.EXE` that re-creates that value (only when trying to access the context menu!). But why? and why only for `.png` and not for `.jpg`? What's so special about PNG files in Windows 7?

Comment: @BillTheApe I missed one of your prior question edits- check my edit

Comment: Note comment #2 (5 hours ago): I **deleted** `UserChoice` **completely** and that didn't help. So the solution to the mystery doesn't lie (yet) in your edit. BTW, it's not me who added `PBrush` to `UserChoice`... And it's not me who's setting the default `.png` ProgID to `png_auto_file`... Some little gremlin in Microsoft is pulling a trick on me and I have no idea what and why.

Comment: Deleting the user choice actually solved the issue for me. Thanks!